# ValueError while splitting - The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I get some data from a CSV

```
% Gain  Original Price  Max Price  ...  S4 Price     S4 RSI        RSI
0  23.529407            0.34      0.420  ...      0.55  64.814813  46.511625
1  20.000000            0.15      0.180  ...      0.18  44.444448  33.333342
2  16.022889            6.99      8.110  ...      5.61  69.565213  35.555565
3  12.399998            2.50      2.810  ...      2.20  96.296300  40.206185
4  18.055554            0.36      0.425  ...      0.47  83.333337  49.038463
```

My code:

```
predict = MachineLearningData["% Gain"]

X = np.array(MachineLearningData.drop(["% Gain"], 1))
Y = np.array(MachineLearningData["% Gain"])
               
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1,stratify= Y)
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
```

I get

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. 
The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

Not sure if this is because my data sample size is too small or I have semantics wrong. Gathering more data is not a problem but I believe the error is with how Y is reading from the % Gain column.

Comment: As the answer below says; stratification is meaningless in regression settings - voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `stratify= Y` from the splitting should resolve the issue. Stratified splits are used for classification problems while you have a regression one.